# Getting thread 1 signal SIGABRT crash error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My app crashed and it doesn't show the reason and unable to find the reason, The crash occurs in for loop, the loop runs and it hit second time in if condition then only crashed.

Here is my code.

```
func removeDuplicatesFromOrderAndOpenOrder() {
    let storedArray = NSMutableArray()
    for i in 0..<logOrderMutArray.count {
        let orderFipsValue:NSNumber = (logOrderMutArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "FIPS") as? NSNumber ?? 0
        let orderAccountNumberValue:String = (logOrderMutArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "AccountNumber") as? String ?? ""
        if i == 0 {
            continue
        }
        for var j in 0..<openOrderMutArray.count {
            let FipsValue:NSNumber = (openOrderMutArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "FIPS") as? NSNumber ?? 0 //----- > Thread 1 signal SIGABRT  shows in this line.
            let AccountNumberValue:String = (openOrderMutArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "AccountNumber") as? String ?? ""
            if orderFipsValue == FipsValue && orderAccountNumberValue == AccountNumberValue {
                let dictMutableCopy = logOrderMutArray[i] as! NSDictionary
                let editDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dictMutableCopy)
                let newDict = openOrderMutArray[j] as! NSDictionary
                let newMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                newMutableArray.add(newDict)
                editDict.setValue(newMutableArray, forKey: "Inspectionlist")
                logOrderMutArray.replaceObject(at: i, with: editDict)
                openOrderMutArray.removeObject(at: j)
                j -= 1
            }
            else {
                storedArray.add(openOrderMutArray[j])
                logOrderMutArray.add(openOrderMutArray[j])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What types does openOrderMutArray hold? Is it possible that the second time the loop runs the "FIPS" value is missing or can't be cast as a NSNumber?

Comment: I checked with "as? NSNumber ?? 0" optional value but it shows same..

Comment: And what does openOrderMutArray[j] point to when it crashes? What kind of object do you store in this array?

Comment: What does `openOrderMutArray` array contain? Try separating the value one by one instead of all in one line to producing the exact error?

Comment: It started in swift 2 so only I use NSArray and NSMutableArray for Unique.@TheTiger

Comment: openOrderMutArray[j] contains collection of dictionary.@andlin

Comment: Refactor your code to get rid of all of the `NS...` and `AnyObject` stuff and use Swift types. Not only will your code be easier to read, but the chances are your error will either be resolved or at the very least you will get a meaningful error from the Swift compiler.

Comment: Try to use the debugger by setting some breakpoints and inspect values local to the for loop.

Comment: If openOrderMutArray contains dictionaries I don't understand why you cast it as AnyObject. Like Paulw11 said, remove all AnyObject stuff.

Comment: Ok i will refactor it.@Paulw11

Comment: Ok thanks..@andlin

Comment: There is a way to stop the execution on the line that crashed your app. In your project, on the left panel, click on "Show the breakpoint navigator" icon (second from right to left), then, on the bottom, click on the plus sign and then "Exception Breakpoint". This is very handy when there is an exception that is hard to find. Hope it helps